# Junit sampler doesnt show up tests without resolving the duplicate reference issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, junit4

*Exported Testscript as JAR and placed it under jmeter/lib/junit

*Placed all project dependency jars under jmeter/lib

*Jmeter has reference to 'xstream' and the project dependency jar 'Browser-Mob' has another reference to 'xstream' that throws an error "Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.addPermission(Lcom/thoughtworks/xstream/security/TypePermission"
Help me resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Method is found in `xstream-1.4.10.jar` which is part of JMeter from version 3.3.

So upgrade your JMeter version and use latest xstream jar

Comment: Problem is having multiple reference to the same class "xstream". Upgrading to latest jar doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @Dorothy Judy you don't have old xstream jar in classpath?

Comment: Project contains 'xstream' jar that comes packaged as part of latest Jmeter and another reference to it as part of the BrowserMobProxy  jar

Answer (score 0):

The situation you ran into is known as [jar hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) so you need to ensure that there are no conflicts between JMeter dependencies and your project dependencies.

I can see the following solutions:

1. Given you have `selenium-webdriver` tag my expectation is that you are trying to automate browser actions. The easier way would be going for [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which has "good" dependencies which don't conflict with JMeters
2. I don't think BrowserMob Proxy depends on xstream, but just in case be aware that you can run it as a separate application in [Standalone mode](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#getting-started-standalone) using JMeter's [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)